# Pass parameter to constructor from template

Tags: angular, typescript

A very basic setup, component:

```
export class LayerComponent {
    public content: string;

    constructor(content: string) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

and its template:

```
<p>{{content}}</p>
```

From another component i would like to (statically) instantiate the component described passing in the content parameter (without the need for binding it). I took the following approach which doesn't work:

```
<ipe-artboard-layer content="Joep"></ipe-artboard-layer>
<ipe-artboard-layer content="Floris"></ipe-artboard-layer>
<ipe-artboard-layer content="Casper"></ipe-artboard-layer>
```

Is the approach possible, adviseable? I'd rather not go for a real binding because it's only to instantiate the component with a one-time initial value for some property of it.

Comment: Did you try this: `constructor(content?: string) { ... }` ?

Comment: I tried, without success. It bugs already over the content="Joep" declaration I guess. Gives a lot of console errors upon loading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible to invoke constructor this way.

What you're looking for is `@Input()` binding:

```
<ipe-artboard-layer [content]="Joep"></ipe-artboard-layer>
```

And in your component:

```
export class LayerComponent {
    @Input()
    public content: string;

    constructor() {}
}
```

Here you can read [more about component interactions](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Comment: I know about this way, but the proposed one feels more natural to me. I saw some material about reading out an attribute as a string in the constructor and then splitting it to get (possibly) multiple parameters out of it but that felt pretty cumbersome. I will stick with your proposed answer for now. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:
Don't why it didn't cross my mind initially, but I think that @ViewChild is your way to go. In your parent component .ts declare:

```js
@ViewChild('layer1') layer1: LayerComponent 
...

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.layer1.content = 'joey';
}
```

then in it's template:

```html
<ipe-artboard-layer #layer1></ipe-artboard-layer>
```

OLD:
It doesn't matter if it's initial, one-time or anything. It may be strange for someone coming from plain JS or React, but Input data binding is the Angular way.
Alternatively you can use class inheritace with same template, but you'd have to  create component for each initial value, which probably is not what you're trying to achieve in long terms.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than a proposed solution. And it does matter because inpunt binding keeps being checked by the Angular change detection mechanism which I preferred to prevent for a perfomance reason. That's why I was wondering if there could be something like template declared constructor arguments for a component.

Comment: Maybe it should, I'm new to posting anything here. You didn't mention that performance is much of your concern. I've edited my answer, hope it's better now and will be useful to you or someone.

Comment: The newly proposed is completely NOT the way to go :/ The usual Angular way of providing parameter values "from outside" is with `@Input`. The question was about providing input parameters only a single time in a component declaration in a template. So `Input` is the usual way but is being "change detected" over and over which I was seeking to prevent by a "one-time-binding" (constructor argument) which isn't possible in Angular nowadays.